# No such table android sqliteassethelper

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite

I know this is a typical question here but all the answers given couldn't solve my problem. I have a prepopulated database(did it with sqlitebrowser) that I copy under my assets/databases folder as it's suggested in https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper manual. The database opens correctly but it gives me the error that there is no such table. It has become really frustrating any help would be highly appreciated.

Code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

public class Database extends SQLiteAssetHelper{
    private static final String DBNAME = "tirinini";
    private static int DBVERSION = 1;

public Database(Context cont){
    super(cont, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
}

public Cursor getPicture(){
    Cursor c;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    c = db.rawQuery("SELECT image, fonimata FROM parquestionpack1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT " + MainMenu.numOfQuestions, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
   }

}
```

and in the activity I use the database, the part that my app crashes is this:

```
db = new Database(PlayTheGameParents.this);

c1 = db.getPicture();
```

The log gives the error on c1 = db.getPicture(); and on the c = db.rawQuery("SELECT image, fonimata FROM parquestionpack1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT " + MainMenu.numOfQuestions, null);

Thx in advance.

EDIT 1:
It can only find the android_metadata table. If it's of any help to anyone.

Logcat:

```
07-24 11:05:33.007: E/SQLiteLog(11862): (1) no such table: paruestionpack1
07-24 11:05:33.017: D/AndroidRuntime(11862): Shutting down VM
07-24 11:05:33.017: W/dalvikvm(11862): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught       exception (group=0x414352a0)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to   start activity   ComponentInfo{com.bnspro.leksopaixnidi/com.bnspro.leksopaixnidi.PlayTheGameParents}:   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: paruestionpack1 (code 1): , while   compiling: SELECT image, fonimata FROM paruestionpack1 LIMIT 10
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: paruestionpack1 (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT image, fonimata FROM paruestionpack1 LIMIT 10
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1108)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:681)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:589)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1420)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1267)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1138)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1344)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at com.bnspro.leksopaixnidi.DBAction.getPicture(DBAction.java:28)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at com.bnspro.leksopaixnidi.PlayTheGameParents.onCreate(PlayTheGameParents.java:55)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
07-24 11:05:33.117: E/AndroidRuntime(11862):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Where is the class that creates the table?

Comment: @HectorWilliam I created the table with sqlitebrowser. I have done it before. Rajesh I've found this also here. But I don't think this is the real problem. Otherwise it wouldhave given me a syntax error or uknown function or something like that.

Comment: Ok thank God i rewrote everything and magically it worked :D. And Rajesh you were right about RANDOM(). I was in complete frustration to see it before :P.